# Regex match negative optional group

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to match `MenuSearch` and `User` in this ocurrencies:

```
/MenuSearch?action=read
/User
```

The following regex match the first case:

```
/\/(.*)(?=\?)/g
```

But doesn't match `User` because they doesn't have `?` character in your line. How can I can make the second regex group optional?

See online:
https://regex101.com/r/qU6hN6/2

Comment: Is that a single example input in which you want to find two matches, or two separate inputs, each of which you want your regex to be able to match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this negation based regex:

```
/^\/([^?]+)/gm
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qU6hN6/4)

Comment: Thanks, worked! I will wait a few minutes to accept as correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`/\/([^?^\n]*)(\?.*)?/g`

This grabs a forward slash, `\/` , followed by any number of non-? non-newline characters, `([^?^\n]*)`, optionally followed by a question mark followed by any number of characters, `(\?.*)?`

The first capture group is the menu item, the second capture group is the query.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the \w metacharacter if you just need to find word characters.

```
\/(\w+)/g
```